# C++: Throwing exceptions, use 'new' or not?

Tags: c++, exception, throw

Is it proper to use `throw new FoobarException(Baz argument);` or `throw FoobarException(Baz argument);`?

When catching I always use `catch(FoobarException& e)` "just in case" but I never could find a solid answer whether I had to use new or not in C++ (Java definitely) or if it was just a preference of the programmer.

Comment: I don't think it will catch if you throw by pointer and attempt to catch by reference, will it?

Comment: If you use new, then `catch(FoobarException&)` will not catch your object.  new creates pointers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Exceptions in C++ should be thrown by value, and caught by reference.

So this is the proper way:

```
try
{
    throw FoobarException(argument);
}
catch( const FoobarException &ex )
{
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

Don't throw an exception created with new, since who's responsible for deleting it is not well-defined. In addition, performing allocations during error handling can throw another exception, obscuring the original problem.

You don't have to catch by const reference (non-const will work fine), but I like doing it anyway. You should however always by reference (not by value) to catch the exception polymorphically. If you don't, the exception's type could be sliced.

Comment: Why exception should always be caught by reference not by value? Are you saying about object slicing problem because of passing derived object by value to a method expects argument of base class object?

Answer (score 8):

unless there is some special requirement not to, I always throw by value and catch by `const` reference. This is because the `new` itself could throw an exception as well, during error handling, it is best to avoid things which can cause exceptions.

Comment: That's right, throwing an exception while another exception is active is essentially forbidden (I think it's UB), so standard `new` is out. You could use some non-throwing allocation if you really had to, but that's still insane :-)

Comment: My 2c's: Just to add to @KerrekSB 's sage advice, it is actually defined behaviour (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate). The aforementioned link also points to a number of other things that are best avoided (such as throwing exceptions from destructors, because then you may wind up raising exceptions while the stack is being unwound for a previously thrown exception).